# Configure reducers of connected-react-router and Redux Toolkit Query properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers, connected-react-router

I am trying to setup reducers of both connected-react-router and RTK Query.
(The old code base has connected-react-router already)
Then I received this error.

[fail to setup connectRouter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UppnO.png)

```
Type 'Reducer<RouterState<unknown>, AnyAction>' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<unknown, AnyAction>'.
Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'RouterState<unknown>'.
```

My "mockApi" is quite simple. "orderApi" is somewhat the same.

```
export const mockApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "mockupPath",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPost: builder.query<MockResonse, number>({
      query: (id) => `/posts/${id}`,
    }),
  }),
})
interface MockResonse { userId: number, id: number, title: string, body: string, }
```

---

While using combineReducers produces no type error,

```
reducer: combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  [mockApi.reducerPath]: mockApi.reducer,
}),
```

but I lose the type of the store.
Knowing the type of the store is a huge advantage in development, so I'm trying to figure out how to solve the error.

May I know if I'm wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This TypeScript error occurs when using `connected-react-router` with newer versions of `history` and `react-router`.

The type for the `connectRouter` function looks like this:

```
export function connectRouter<S = LocationState>(history: History<S>)
    : Reducer<RouterState<S>>
```

([source](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/c6609e335c1b6bd3a2fce163d4d19beeb6d6a7ea/index.d.ts#L107))

You can see that it is a generic function where the generic type parameter `S` refers to the type of the `state` that is stored in your history.

If you have a new version of `history` (5.2+), then `History<S>` is now a TypeScript error because [the `History` interface is no longer generic](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/ba1cd3cf50465af8e1a89cc4f088c6372c10c12b/packages/history/index.ts#L188).  This is [a recent change](https://github.com/remix-run/history/commit/04a01ad4500720e26ebbf3d9cfefbd6c1a86be84) which was released in `history` version 5.2.0.

You can fix the error by explicitly setting the generic type parameter for the `connectRouter` function call to `unknown`:

```
router: connectRouter<unknown>(history)
```

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [mockApi.reducerPath]: mockApi.reducer,
    router: connectRouter<unknown>(history)
  }
})
```

The inferred type of the router reducer is now `Reducer<RouterState<unknown>, AnyAction>`.

Comment: Now that I take another look at it, indeed every reducer "goes" with a state it operates on.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can use Type Assertions here.
https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/195

```
router: connectRouter(history) as Reducer,
```

Comment: `as Reducer` is kind of garbage because it doesn't contain any state type.  It should be `as Reducer<RouterState, AnyAction>` or something.  I've used these two packages together before without issue (until I finally got rid of connected-react-router).  I will check my code and leave an answer.